# How to test an async function in an event listener with Jest?

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs, event-listener

I have an event listener that runs an asynchronous function, and removes some elements from the DOM after completion:

```
async function fetchAndRemove() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/endpoint-that-returns-json')

    const result = await response.json()
    if (result.status === 'Success') {
      document.querySelector('.my-element').remove()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function setupListeners () {
  const button = document.querySelector('.my-button')
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetchAndRemove()
  })
}


setupListeners()
```

In my test, I have:

```
import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock';

test('it removes the element after clicking', () => {
  fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ status: 'Success' }))
  setupListeners()
  document.querySelector('.my-button').click() // .click comes from JSDOM

  expect(document.querySelector('.my-element')).toBeNull()
}
```

However that doesn't work because I believe in the test, setting up the event listener and clicking the button runs synchronously and doesn't wait for the async work to finish.

I tried this idea but no good results:

```
test('it removes the element after clicking', async () => {
  fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ status: 'Success' }))
  setupListeners()
  await Promise.resolve(document.querySelector('.my-button').click())

  expect(document.querySelector('.my-element')).toBeNull()
}
```

Comment: fetch doesn't have mockResponse method. If you're using something like jest-fetch-mock, this should be specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong because DOM events don't involve promises and `await Promise.resolve` is redundant:

```
await Promise.resolve(document.querySelector('.my-button').click())
```

It creates one-tick delay and that's all.

Since `fetchAndRemove` is referred in the same module it's defined, it cannot be spied, so `fetch` promise should be chained in order to maintain correct execution order.

Considering that `fetch` is a spy, it can be:

```
  fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ status: 'Success' }))
  setupListeners()
  document.querySelector('.my-button').click()
  await fetch.mock.results[0].value; // delay for fetch()
  await null; // another delay for res.json()
  expect(fetch).toBeCalledWith('/endpoint-that-returns-json')
  expect(document.querySelector('.my-element')).toBeNull()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: In your code global fetch is not mocked, I expect that fetch in fetchAndRemove and in tests are not the same. Don't import it like `import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock'`. See https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock#to-setup-for-all-tests . It likely should be done this way because it's almost never desirable to perform real requests in tests. In case you expect for a function to be called, it's preferable to assert this, see the update.