# AwaitFor doesnt wait the callback to be called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this simple test example here whereas i want the waitAFor to wait the fetch method to be called but the test ends after 3 sec. It doesnt wait for 7 sec.

```
const TestComponent = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
         fetch();
     }, 6000);
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};


jest.mock("./service");

describe("Test", () => {
  let container = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
    container = render(<TestComponent />);
  });


  test("should fetch", async () => {
    await waitFor(() => expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such operations aren't supposed to wait for unspecified amount of time, this could result in pending process.

The documentation states that `waitFor` fails on timeout:

> The default timeout is 1000ms which will keep you under Jest's default timeout of 5000ms.

If a delay is expected, timeout values can be specified explicitly:

```
  test("should fetch", async () => {
    await waitFor(() => expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1), { timeout: 8000 });
  }, 10000);
```

Since long asynchronous operations like HTTP requests aren't common in tests, it's impractical to wait for them in realtime, this is what Jest fake timer API is for.

Comment: So why bother even use waitFor?

Comment: No not rely on the implementation. This conforms to the idea of RTL as blackbox testing lib. And makes sense for cases when it's hard or impossible to track the points that need to be waited, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094817/3731501 , 2 `await`s are fragile already, this can become more flaky for nested async calls. waitFor is commonly used to assert the result like component markup. This example is synthetic and not representative. Why would there be such a big and exact delay with no impact on DOM? You won't hit a timeout in tests with most real-world comps with async side effects